# Whole page goes to the left when PHP code is inserted?

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer

Is there a reason the back-end PHP code could affect the layout of a page? This only happens in IE. In Firefox and Chrome, everything looks fine.

Thing is, we have this HTML code, then a back-end code for the functions on that page is inserted by `<?php include "[name of file]";?>`. The php file we included has no styling in it whatsoever but it mysteriously makes the whole page go to the left edge (instead of centered). If we remove that file from the page, it renders normally.

We have learned that if we comment out a certain part of the code on that file (view below), the layout gets fixed:

```
//function position_list() {
    global $db, $core, $global;
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    include ROOT.'templates/listing.php';
    ob_flush();
//}
```

I'm just wondering if anybody has encountered a similar problem? What could be wrong?

Comment: what is it that's being `include`'d?

Comment: Can you please show the contents of listing.php? And where/how do you call position_list()

Comment: @stillstanding: The one being included is a list of different functions for a particular page (it's sort of a calendar for booking events).

Comment: and what do those "different functions" do? are you sure they don't output anything that may alter the page?

Comment: Okay, now we did some comparison. One with that file included and one without it. The only difference when we looked at the source file is that there is a space before the doctype on the one with the distorted layout. Could that little space be causing all that problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that "little space" could be causing the problem. Internet Explorer expects the doctype to be the very first thing in your document. It even chokes when the only thing preceding it is the XML tag that begins XHTML documents. When there's anything before the doctype, IE doesn't realize the doctype is there at all, and it switches to quirks mode. If you want to be sure, save the output as a normal file on your computer, remove the space, and load that file.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: Yea, the white space does trigger IE quirks mode. We removed it and now it's fine. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the source in IE with and without the include line. Is it what you expect? Are there any PHP warnings?

Quite odd to see you comment out the `function {}` part without commenting out the body of the function. You're effectively now calling `position_list();` whatever. Which of the lines is it that is causing the rendering to change?

If this is all before the doctyle and `<html>` tag then it could be that the output is triggering the browser to render in quirks mode, rather than standard compliance mode.

Comment: Hmm, actually I just now tried rendering it in quirks mode. I mean, using the one with the correct layout but in IE quirks mode and the rendering is exaclty the same as the one with the php code included. So it seems that something in the code forces the IE to display it in quirks mode.

Comment: Solved it now. It's indeed that one "space" before the doctype. We removed it and now IE renders it in the standards mode. Anyway, thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a problem with the included code, not with styles but with broken tags. Some nesting is going on and a tag is being closed by something other than what opened it or something is being left open. You should try running the output code through a strict html validator to find the error.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are putting IE into quirks mode. If you are using margin:auto; on an element, IE tends to ignore it in quirks mode.

Make sure that the doctype is the very first thing in the file being outputted (no line breaks, spaces, comments, etc.). Also, make sure your page validates against the given doctype.

If the above doesn't work, please post more code.